# Find out if direct links are available

Tags: box-api

How do I know if a direct link is available before I generate it? In other words, how do I now if the user account is free or paid?

Checking the enterprise field of the user object does not help since a free account can be an enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

As as far as I know there is no API to fetch if user is free or paid at the given moment.

So I'd suggest a hack. 
You can query max_upload_size for the Box user from this endpoint. http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-the-current-users-information

If upload limit is smaller or equal than 250MB ( 262144000 ), then it is free user.

Note, that this limits can change any time, so it is quite fragile hack.
But can get you going in the meantime.

Comment: Seems that's not correct. My max upload size is 2147483648. Still I am a free user.

`{ "can_see_managed_users" = 1; enterprise = { id = x; name = "Enterprise for x x"; type = enterprise; }; id = x;  "is_exempt_from_device_limits" = 0; "is_sync_enabled" = 1;  "max_upload_size" = 2147483648; role = admin; type = user;
}`